# two random inequalities as conditionals for an if-then loop in python

Tags: python

I am in a conundrum. I am trying to figure out why the incrementing counter isn't increment. It returns a value of only one. The idea is that are a random time that incrementing counter t_years would go down to zero and begin again while another counter would just keep running.

```
import time, math, random

t0 = time.time()
average_life_span = .10

while True:
    time.sleep(.01)
    a = time.time()
    age = int (a*1000) - int(t0*1000) #millis

    t_years = 0
    while (int (age) < int (random.normalvariate (average_life_span, 1))):
            t_years = 0
    else:
            t_years = t_years + .01

    print age, t_years
```

Comment: @roippi, good point. There should probably be logic in the inner while loop that changes the value of age. Otherwise, if the while loop begins, it will never, ever end...

Comment: No it isn't an infinite loop. The right-hand side is an expression that generates a random number. It will be different each time through. So it will only loop infinitely if it's less than the entire range; if it's anywhere within the range it will loop a finite (but nondeterministic) number of times, which is a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `t_years = 0` before the inner loop, then again each time through the loop.

When you finally finish the inner loop, in the `else` clause, you add `.01`. So now it's guaranteed to be `0.01`.

The next time through the outer loop, you again reset it to `0`, and then do so over and over again, and finally add `.01` to that at the end. So it's again guaranteed to be `0.01`.

If you want the number to start at `0` and increment by `0.01` each time through the outer loop, don't keep resetting it to `0`. Do this:

```
t_years = 0

while True:
    time.sleep(.01)
    a = time.time()
    age = int (a*1000) - int(t0*1000) #millis

    while (int (age) < int (random.normalvariate (average_life_span, 1))):
        pass
    else:
        t_years = t_years + .01

    print age, t_years
```

---

I'm not sure what this loop is actually supposed to be doing. I don't think it will ever be triggered, but even if it is, all it can do is delay for a random amount of time burning as much CPU as possible while doing so. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: while (int (age) < int (random.normalvariate (average_life_span, 1))):
            pass

Comment: that works. so the idea is that while the int age is less than the life span, it will keep incrementing. But there should be a time when the age gets beyond lifespan and resets t_years to zero.

Comment: there are two incrementing values. t_years dies off at random intervals.

Comment: @AaronGilbee: There is nothing in your code that decrements `t_years`. There's only code that resets it to `0`, and code that increments it by `0.1`. Maybe what you posted here isn't your real code?

Comment: there are two things going on. this code is intended to run the duration of the program. [age = time] while this happens, there is another time interval being counted [t_years = growth and death] within the larger time loop. The processes in this situation are always additive, which is why there is no decrement. It grows. It dies.